# How to call textBox codebehind TextChanged event from checkbox click lying inside GridView Row?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a Gridview in which each row has a Checkbox and TextBox . I am doing some work on textchange event as below

```
protected void txtRemarks_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow grow = ((TextBox)sender).Parent.Parent as GridViewRow;

    GenerateCheckedDataAndStore(grow); // Basically populates a datatable from Viewstate


}
```

This I need to do on click event of checkbox also. I have tried using `__doPostBack()` function but doesnot work.

How can I successfully fire code behind **textbox change event** from clicking on adjacent checkbox ? Please help.

```
<asp:GridView id="grdView" runat="server">
<Columns>
 <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="2%">
     <HeaderTemplate>
       <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkAll" Style="text-align: left !important;" />
     </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
       <%-- <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkSelect" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkSelect_CheckedChanged" />--%>

       <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkSelect"  />
       <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnNo" runat="server" Value="<%#Bind('InvoiceNo')%>" />
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remarks" ItemStyle-Width="12%">
     <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtRemarks" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtRemarks_TextChanged" Text="<%#Bind('Remarks')%>" TextMode="MultiLine"  AutoPostBack="true" ></asp:TextBox>
          <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnRemarks" runat="server" />
       </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
.
.
.
</Columns>
</GridView>
```

**Please note**
My aim is to call  `GenerateCheckedDataAndStore(grow);` on checkbox click event.

### Edit

As suggested in by @Jared in comments below i am calling textchange from checkchanged of checkbox. But strangely the gridview row being captured from checkbpox doesnot udate but remains same as whichever row was selected first.

```
 protected void txtRemarks_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        GridViewRow grow= null;
        if(sender is TextBox)
            grow = ((TextBox)sender).Parent.Parent as GridViewRow;
        else if(sender is CheckBox)
            grow = ((CheckBox)sender).Parent.Parent as GridViewRow;
        GenerateCheckedDataAndStore(grow);

  }
```

Comment: Why not write a _WebMethod_ (to do the processing) and call it via jQuery ajax? Or Else write a private method which accepts a parameter _grow_ and call it from event handlers of both textbox(txtRemarks_TextChanged) & checkbox(chkSelect_CheckedChanged).

Comment: Try using the [OnCheckedChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.oncheckedchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) attribute of the checkbox: `OnCheckedChanged="txtRemarks_TextChanged"`

Comment: @Rahul How to find gridview row in webmethod in which checkbox was clicked ?

Comment: @mhasan - You can identify the row at client as well, but I guess you must be intresented in row items and not the row itself.

Comment: @JaredBeach .. awesome trick .. but right now it is throwing `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'.`

Comment: @RahulSingh yes i am extracting values from gridview row and populating viewstate..

Comment: I have rectified error unable to cast object of type  but strangely only the first gridview row in which checkbox was clicked the first time is being passed evertime

Comment: @mhasan - That's because of _Parent.Parent_ code. Check my answer you should use **NamingContainer** instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add to the checkbox following code:

```
AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="txtRemarks_TextChanged"
```

Update:

You will need to cast sender to Control instead of TextBox to your action to work.